# Removing OBX segments from HL7 message based on OBX-3.2 value

Tags: tcl, hl7

Does anyone have experience with removing segments from an HL7 message based on a value that exists in a field?  I have seen scripts that Kill a message based on a certain value, but I would like to file the rest of the message.  The language and platform being used is tcl and Cloverleaf.

Comment: What kind of languages/platforms are you using to modify your HL7 messages? Add that information to the question. Also, add a code sample of what you have tried and found not to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are after. Here's how I would remove a given OBX segment. I assume there are repeating OBX segments so this would be under an Iterate.

Add an IF statement:
If 1(0).1(0).3(%g1).OBX(0).#3(0).[1] eq =value
   ("value" is whatever value you are wanting this to look for.)
Then just do a pathcopy:
  Source: @null
  Destination: 1(0).1(0).3(%g1).OBX(0)

Of course the exact path of the OBX listed depends on the variant that you are using. But in the context of an iterate statement this should remove just the OBX with the defined value and not touch the other OBX segments.